# Set Combobox Name in Json Property using C#

Tags: c#, json, properties, combobox

I create a long list and assign it to a combobox. Like Berlin, Kiel, Munchen. I implement json serialization for each of this city. My RootObject class is-

```
 public class RootObject
{
    [JsonProperty("City")]
    public List<Cityname> city { get; set; }
}
```

My json serialization method is-

```
public void ToJsonForCity(string CityName)
    {
        var startPath = Application.StartupPath;
        string folderName = Path.Combine(startPath, "OneCityJson");
        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(folderName);
        string fileName = CityName + ".json";
        var path = Path.Combine(folderName, fileName);

        var city = new Cityname { Tourist = new List<Tourist>(), Hotel = new List<Hotel>() };
        DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(startPath + @"\OnePoiJson\"+ CityName);

        foreach (var file in d.GetFiles())
        {
            using (StreamReader fi = File.OpenText(file.FullName))
            {
                JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
                Tourist tourist = (Tourist)serializer.Deserialize(fi, typeof(Tourist));
                city.Tourist.Add(tourist);
            }


        }

        using (StreamReader fi = File.OpenText(@"C:\C# tutorial Backup\joint_josn\joint_josn\bin\Debug\Hotel.json"))
        {
            JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
            Hotel hotel = (Hotel)serializer.Deserialize(fi, typeof(Hotel));
            city.Hotel.Add(hotel);
        }

        using (StreamWriter file = File.CreateText(path))
        {
            JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer { Formatting = Formatting.Indented };
            //serializer.Serialize(file, new { City = city });
            serializer.Serialize(file, new RootObject { city = new List<Cityname> { city } });
        }


    }
```

After serialization it comes in this way-

```
{
"City": [ //as I set Json property City
   {
    "Tourist": [
    {
      "Name": "Flensburg Firth",
      "Shorttext": "Flensburg Firth or Flensborg Fjord  is the westernmost inlet of the Baltic Sea. It forms part of the border between Germany to the south and Denmark to the north. Its length....\n\n",
      "GeoCoordinates": {
  ................
```

In my Form.cs I call this method in this way-

```
  private void Full_City_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OneCompleteCityJson city_json = new OneCompleteCityJson();
        city_json.ToJsonForCity(comboBox1.Text);

    }
```

Now I want to know how can I set Combox item as a Name such as "Flensburg" or "Berlin" etc instead of "City"

Comment: Can we see the code within `city_jason.ToJsonForCity()` - problem is likely in there.

Comment: @Gabe yes. I updated my question and gave the full code.